# cloud firestore data not loding

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database in my DbQuery class

```
    public  static  void loadPaperData(MyCompletelistener completelistener){
    g_paperList.clear();
    g_firestore.collection("SCHOOL").document(g_boardList.get(g_selected_board_index).getDocID()).collection("PAPER_LIST").document("PAPER_INFO"
    ).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            int NoOfPaper = g_boardList.get(g_selected_board_index).getNoOfPaper();
            for (int i=1; i<=NoOfPaper; i++){
                g_paperList.add(new PaperModel(documentSnapshot.getString("PAPER"+ String.valueOf(i)+"_ID"),documentSnapshot.getString("PAPER"+String
                        .valueOf(i)+"_URL")));
            }

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            completelistener.onFailure();
        }
    });

}
```

and my PaperActivity is

```
DbQuery.loadPaperData(new MyCompletelistener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            adapter = new paperAdapter(DbQuery.g_paperList);
            paperView.setAdapter(adapter);
            progress_Dialog.dismiss();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {
            Toast.makeText(PaperActivity.this,"Something Went Wrong ! please Try Again Later !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progress_Dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

when I initially define the data it is working but when I connect with firestore database it is not loading[image: it is showing like this from 2 hours]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to call the `completelistener.OnSuccess()` after downloading the data.

```
public  static  void loadPaperData(MyCompletelistener completelistener){
    g_paperList.clear();
    g_firestore.collection("SCHOOL").document(g_boardList.get(g_selected_board_index).getDocID()).collection("PAPER_LIST").document("PAPER_INFO"
    ).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            int NoOfPaper = g_boardList.get(g_selected_board_index).getNoOfPaper();
            for (int i=1; i<=NoOfPaper; i++){
                g_paperList.add(new PaperModel(documentSnapshot.getString("PAPER"+ String.valueOf(i)+"_ID"),documentSnapshot.getString("PAPER"+String
                        .valueOf(i)+"_URL")));
    
            }
    completelistener.onSuccess();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            completelistener.onFailure();
        }
    });

}
```

By the way, I would suggest you send the data across the interface callback instead of using the public ArrayList, for example, using this interface:

```
public interface CompleteListener {
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<PaperModel> paperModelList);
    void onFailure(Exception e);
}
```